# Correctly building an array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have an object:

```
cars = {
  'toyota': {
    'year': 2015,
    'color': 'blue'
  },
  'mazda': {
    'year': 2017,
    'color': 'white'
  }
}
```

I would like to iterate through the vehicles in the `cars` object and push them to another array.

```
for ( carMake in cars ) {
  $scope.newCarsArray.push(cars[carMake]);
}
```

The above correctly pushes each `carMake` object into the `$scope.newCarsArray` array. However, this only pushes the **contents** (for ex: year and color) and not the vehicle name (like toyota and mazda). How can I push each entire object (including vehicle name) into `$scope.newCarsArray` without altering the original object?

I thought the following would work, but it only pushes the car make object **name as a string**.

```
for ( carMake in cars ) {
  $scope.newCarsArray.push(carMake);
}
```

**Desired output:**

```
$scope.newCarsArray = [
  {
    toyota: {
      'year': 2015,
      'color': 'blue'
    }
  },
  {
    mazda: {
      'year': 2017,
      'color': 'white'
     }
  }
];
```

Comment: What is the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case if you need `car` as part of array item:

```
angular.forEach(cars, function(item, key) {
    var newItem = item;
    newItem.car = key;
    $scope.newCarsArray.push(newItem);
  });
```

*Output:*

```
[
  {
    "year": 2015,
    "color": "blue",
    "car": "toyota"
  },
  {
    "year": 2017,
    "color": "white",
    "car": "mazda"
  }
]
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z18o68qz/)

Comment: Not exactly the structure I was looking for, but this works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a new object with the key name and push that:

```
Objects.keys(cars).forEach(function(car) {
    $scope.newCarsArray.push({
        [car]:cars[car]
    });
}); //Outputs like: [{"toyota": {}}, ..]
```

Comment: I tried this in a fiddle, works like a charm. Thank you. I couldn't get it working in my project, because my linter was freaking out on the `[car]:cars[car]` line.

Comment: @bruh - Yeah that'll happen, I believe it's ES6 syntax.